# Beautifulsoup selector in Python returns blank result set for valid selector

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

We want to scrape some content from [this](https://bankcodesfinder.com/world-postal-codes/india) webpage. The HTML of the element we are interested in is this (`div.white-bg-border-radius-kousik.shadow-kousik-effect.mb-2`).

[image]

For this, we are trying to use this selector in `BeautifulSoup` (Python). It does not work. I tried three four variants, they did not work as well, the HTML shows that this element is present 36 times in the page. The selectors return either blank set or 2-3 results, so I am obviously missing something. Need to find out the right way of doing it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import urllib.request

url = "https://bankcodesfinder.com/world-postal-codes/india"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        html = str(response.read())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        elements = soup.find_all('div.white-bg-border-radius-kousik.shadow-kousik-effect.mb-2') # This returns blank set
        elements2 = soup.findAll('div', class_=['shadow-kousik-effect', 'mb-2']) #returns just 3 elements, whereas this is a subset class search of the original list of 3 classes, so this should return at least 36 elements
        elements3 = soup.select('div.shadow-kousik-effect') # returns just 3 results
```

Comment: @Ouroborus Verified the `html` text, it contains all these 36 elements. I saw it here as well: `view-source:https://bankcodesfinder.com/world-postal-codes/india`

Comment: I played around with it a little. Seems like `html.parser` doesn't like the page's html. Using `soup = BeautifulSoup(response)` instead (uses the default parser, I believe `lxml`) gave me something that lets `soup.select('div.white-bg-border-radius-kousik.shadow-kousik-effect.mb-2')` pull out the particular divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with your `response` which on my machine gives tags with trailing `\r\n`.

```html
<div\r\n class="white-bg-border-radius-kousik shadow-kousik-effect mb-2">

 <a \r\n="" class="nounderline" href="/world...>
```

Using [`requests`](https://fr.python-requests.org/en/latest/), your css selector returns the 35 elements (*search-box excluded*).

```
import requests

url = "https://bankcodesfinder.com/world-postal-codes/india"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

css = "div.white-bg-border-radius-kousik.shadow-kousik-effect.mb-2"

regions = [list(tag.stripped_strings) for tag in soup.select(css)]
```

Output :

```
# len(regions) # 35
[
    ['ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS', '102 Branches'],
    ['ANDHRA PRADESH', '10493 Branches'],
    ['ARUNACHAL PRADESH', '302 Branches'],
    ['ASSAM', '4022 Branches'],
    ['BIHAR', '9113 Branches'],
    ...
]
```